# Can't submit entityform after ajax callback on select element

Tags: 8, ajax

I followed the advice from [this link](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/before-you-start/2019-12-05/an-illegal-choice-has-been-detected-after-recharge-select) and migrated the code populating my ajax into buildForm(), and all is well. Select list is populated by ajax and elements are preserved even after form submit. Problem is that I get the following error when I try to submit the form -

```
The value you selected is not a valid choice
```

I've tried adding the popular `'#validated'=TRUE` option to my ajax select, but this causes 2 things to happen

1. My ajax callback only successfully replaces the content of the
   select once, subsequent calls have no effect whatsoever, the old
   content of the select remains
2. I get a really bad error when I try to
   submit the form `"Website encountered an error"`. Checking the logs
   shows the following:

> [client ::1:40776] TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::massageFormValues() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/chibuzo/Software/Dev/Src/Web/tpl_website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php on line 390 in /home/chibuzo/Software/Dev/Src/Web/tpl_website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php on line 537 #0 /home/chibuzo/Software/Dev/Src/Web/tpl_website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php(390): Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase->massageFormValues()\n#1 /home/chibuzo/Software/Dev/Src/Web/tpl_website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity/EntityFormDisplay.php(232): Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase->extractFormValues()```

So if I use `'#validated' = TRUE`, my ajax callback runs only once and shows the error above on form submit,
And if I remove `'#validated'=TRUE`, my form fails to submit and shows `"You have selected an invalid choice" error"`.
I even tried to update the `$form_state` variable to contain the same `#options` values populated by  my ajax callback and nothing changes, also `$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE)` does nothing.

I'm almost giving up the idea of using ajax at all, since I've spent more than a week debugging just an ajax select element. First, the ajax callback wasnt being reached at all, now ajax populate happens, but cant submit form. It's just that I have this feeling that I've done 90% of the work involved, its just remaining 1 thing which I dont know. That remaining 10% is what I decided to throw this to the community. I'm sure someone else must know! Thanks for your help, guys...

Comment: Why do you have `$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
    
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);` at the top of your buildForm method?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to have the actual code you wrote to check if there are some errors.
If you check my [relative question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/299377/74024) you can crossreference your code to check if there's something wrong (mine is currently working).

I'd suggest to:

1. apply [the patch of this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3137947)
2. if still not working do the same workaround I've used: check the $triggering_element to populate the select options only in the opportune moments of the form build.